Is there a parameter problem, or not working with this method?
I wanted to predict the disease type using a function with a given string parameter. The parameter can contain more than one string. But it always gives an error message: KeyError: 'skin_rash'
This is a code sample which I found on Geeks for geeks: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/disease-prediction-using-machine-learning/
The datasets for this function can be found on Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/kaushil268/disease-prediction-using-machine-learning/data
Here is my code:
symptoms = X.columns.values

Here are the symptoms:
['itching' 'skin_rash' 'nodal_skin_eruptions' 'continuous_sneezing'
 'shivering' 'chills' 'joint_pain' 'stomach_pain' 'acidity'
 'ulcers_on_tongue' 'muscle_wasting' 'vomiting' 'burning_micturition'
 'spotting_ urination' 'fatigue' 'weight_gain' 'anxiety'
 'cold_hands_and_feets' 'mood_swings' 'weight_loss' 'restlessness'
 'lethargy' 'patches_in_throat' 'irregular_sugar_level' 'cough'
 'high_fever' 'sunken_eyes' 'breathlessness' 'sweating' 'dehydration'
 'indigestion' 'headache' 'yellowish_skin' 'dark_urine' 'nausea'
 'loss_of_appetite' 'pain_behind_the_eyes' 'back_pain' 'constipation'
 'abdominal_pain' 'diarrhoea' 'mild_fever' 'yellow_urine'
 'yellowing_of_eyes' 'acute_liver_failure' 'fluid_overload'
 'swelling_of_stomach' 'swelled_lymph_nodes' 'malaise'
 'blurred_and_distorted_vision' 'phlegm' 'throat_irritation'
 'redness_of_eyes' 'sinus_pressure' 'runny_nose' 'congestion' 'chest_pain'
 'weakness_in_limbs' 'fast_heart_rate' 'pain_during_bowel_movements'
 'pain_in_anal_region' 'bloody_stool' 'irritation_in_anus' 'neck_pain'
 'dizziness' 'cramps' 'bruising' 'obesity' 'swollen_legs'
 'swollen_blood_vessels' 'puffy_face_and_eyes' 'enlarged_thyroid'
 'brittle_nails' 'swollen_extremeties' 'excessive_hunger'
 'extra_marital_contacts' 'drying_and_tingling_lips' 'slurred_speech'
 'knee_pain' 'hip_joint_pain' 'muscle_weakness' 'stiff_neck'
 'swelling_joints' 'movement_stiffness' 'spinning_movements'
 'loss_of_balance' 'unsteadiness' 'weakness_of_one_body_side'
 'loss_of_smell' 'bladder_discomfort' 'foul_smell_of urine'
 'continuous_feel_of_urine' 'passage_of_gases' 'internal_itching'
 'toxic_look_(typhos)' 'depression' 'irritability' 'muscle_pain'
 'altered_sensorium' 'red_spots_over_body' 'belly_pain'
 'abnormal_menstruation' 'dischromic _patches' 'watering_from_eyes'
 'increased_appetite' 'polyuria' 'family_history' 'mucoid_sputum'
 'rusty_sputum' 'lack_of_concentration' 'visual_disturbances'
 'receiving_blood_transfusion' 'receiving_unsterile_injections' 'coma'
 'stomach_bleeding' 'distention_of_abdomen'
 'history_of_alcohol_consumption' 'fluid_overload.1' 'blood_in_sputum'
 'prominent_veins_on_calf' 'palpitations' 'painful_walking'
 'pus_filled_pimples' 'blackheads' 'scurring' 'skin_peeling'
 'silver_like_dusting' 'small_dents_in_nails' 'inflammatory_nails'
 'blister' 'red_sore_around_nose' 'yellow_crust_ooze']



 
# Creating a symptom index dictionary to encode the
# input symptoms into numerical form
symptom_index = {}
for index, value in enumerate(symptoms):
    symptom = " ".join([i for i in value.split("_")])
    symptom_index[symptom] = index
 
data_dict = {
    "symptom_index":symptom_index,
    "predictions_classes":encoder.classes_
}
 
# Defining the Function
# Input: string containing symptoms separated by commas
# Output: Generated predictions by models
def predictDisease(symptoms):
    symptoms = symptoms.split(",")
     
    # creating input data for the models
    input_data = [0] * len(data_dict["symptom_index"])
    for symptom in symptoms:
        index = data_dict["symptom_index"][symptom]
        input_data[index] = 1
         
    # reshaping the input data and converting it
    # into suitable format for model predictions
    input_data = np.array(input_data).reshape(1,-1)
     
    # generating individual outputs
    rf_prediction = data_dict["predictions_classes"][final_rf_model.predict(input_data)[0]]
    nb_prediction = data_dict["predictions_classes"][final_nb_model.predict(input_data)[0]]
    svm_prediction = data_dict["predictions_classes"][final_svm_model.predict(input_data)[0]]
     
    # making final prediction by taking mode of all predictions
    final_prediction = mode([rf_prediction, nb_prediction, svm_prediction])[0][0]
    predictions = {
        "rf_model_prediction":rf_prediction,
        "naive_bayes_prediction":nb_prediction,
        "svm_model_prediction":svm_prediction,
        "final_prediction":final_prediction
    }
    return predictions
 
# Testing the function
print(predictDisease("itching,skin_rash,nodal_skin_eruptions"))

But i get this error:
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_28380/3227896746.py in <module>
     45 
     46 # Testing the function
---> 47 print(predictDisease("itching,skin_rash,nodal_skin_eruptions"))

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_28380/3227896746.py in predictDisease(symptoms)
     22     input_data = [0] * len(data_dict["symptom_index"])
     23     for symptom in symptoms:
---> 24         index = data_dict["symptom_index"][symptom]
     25         input_data[index] = 1
     26 

KeyError: 'skin_rash'

I tried to give the parameter with different formats(set, array, list), but it does not work and always gives the KeyError: 'skin_rash'
How can I resolve this problem?
If anyone could help me, i really would appreciate it! thanks

Maybe a typo but your symptoms list only contains one string. Also, please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example. The code shown cannot be run due to missing dependencies

data_dict['symptom_index'] contains a dictionary of symptom names as keys and their index position in the symptoms list but the key name is different from the name in the symptoms list. The names of the symptom keys contain space instead of underscore in the symptoms list. That is why the key is not found.
Try:
index = data_dict["symptom_index"][symptom.replace("_", " ")]

I didn't check the rest of the code logic, so I don't know if there are any other problems in this code.

The symptom_index dictionary does not get constructed as expected because the symptoms list contains a single string

@SIGHUP As far as I know symptoms = X.columns.values return list. I believe that it is a list and not a single string. I'm not sure where the commas have disappeared. However, when he created the symptom_index dictionary, the key was generated by symptom = " ".join([i for i in value.split("")]) which is the same as value.replace("", " ") and this is why I suggested my solution for the error (the first key, 'itching', contains no '_' so it passes, the second key, 'skin_rash', has been replaced with 'skin rash', so it failed). - not sure why underscore doesn't show on comment

My comment is based on what I can see in the question. I make no assumption about the reality

@SIGHUP I get it, but he shows how he generates the symptoms and not how he printed out the list. It makes some sense, right?
